# Compile-time error wanted for List<>.Sort() with no sort specification

Tags: c#, .net

Is there some way of defining a class such that if I mistakenly attempt to sort a List<> of the objects with no sort specifications it will generate a compile-time error?

So when I correctly specify, for example

```
listOfMyObjects.Sort(MyObject.CompareFieldNames);
```

it will be accepted, but if I forget and specify

```
listOfMyObjects.Sort();
```

then I'll get a compile-time error.

(I do realize that I'll get a runtime-error - but what I'd prefer is some way of getting a compile-time error.)

EDIT:

Just to make it very clear, I **want** to get a compile-time error for the second example above.

The situation, which I find myself in occasionally, is that I have a class with several different Comparison<> methods. Let's say it can be sorted by FieldName or it can be sorted by DateOfCreation. Now, what I want to avoid is accidently/mistakenly thinking, "oh yes, good old object X, it's sortable by date of creation, so I'll just sort this list with Sort() and go merrily on my way ...", but in fact the default sorting method is sort by FieldName (so the sorting is wrong) or there is no default sorting method (so I get a runtime error).

So I want to force myself (or anyone else working with my object) to remember that there are several ways to sort the object, and one of the methods should be explicitly chosen.

Comment: I doubt that it's possible. How should the compiler know?

Comment: The only way to do it is to define your own List<> and in the Sort method include to pass a parameter in.

Comment: @azhar: OK, but then I'd want some way of preventing myself from forgetting and using List<> instead of my custom List<>. That's not possible, is it? Defining a class such that it is not eligible for use with List<>?

Comment: What if your list gets passed to a generic method that performs a default sort - something like that would be tricky for the compiler to find.

Comment: @rawling: That's OK, that will result in a runtime error. I just want to avoid the more obvious mistakes at compile time, if possible.

Comment: Parameterless `Sort` is method on the List class.  You are asking for List to not behave as a List.  This is not possible.

Comment: @RenniePet Well yes, you have to remember to use the custom List rather than the pre-defined list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a custom FxCop rule, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30666/7-Steps-to-Write-Your-Own-Custom-Rule-using-FXCOP) for a tutorial.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/) for Code Analysis.

Comment: Thanks, this could be a viable method. I'm not using FxCop, but I am using Visual Studio Code Analysis. Do you happen to have any links for tutorials for that program?

Comment: OK, I have taken a look at the idea of creating a custom rule for Code Analysis, and I'm pretty sure that would work. I ended up doing something else. I have a post-processing program that round-trips the MSIL and does some homemade obfuscation, and I decided I could add this checking to that program easier than learning how to create a custom rule for Code Analysis, partly because the debugging of custom rules seems problematic. But thanks for your answer - the idea of doing this checking at build time but not as a compiler error made me see the light.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by sub-classing and then with the `ObsoleteAttribute` - not ideal, but you'll get an error:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
  public MyList() {}
  public MyList(int capacity) : base(capacity) {}
  public MyList(IEnumerable<T> range) : base(range) {}

  [Obsolete("Please do not use this method", true)]
  public new void Sort(){ throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}

public void Test() 
{
  var l = new MyList<string>();
  l.Sort(); //<--- compile-time error
}
```

Only works, however, if the compile-time type of `l` is `MyList<T>`, because you're just defining a new `Sort` method that replaces the base version - but it's not `virtual`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would work, but it would open up a new way for me to make an error, by forgetting to use MyList<> instead of List<>. (It's difficult to make something foolproof, especially when the potential fool is myself.)

Answer (score 1):

Forcing compile time error is not possible. You can set rules like Obsolete but that are just workaround.

Comment: Might want to be a little bit more specific there.  You can force a compile time error anywhere with `#error 'Forced compile time error'`; although it doesn't work in this scenario it's used in many others